# Cambiar comportamiento de QPushButton para salir de diálogo o salir de aplicación

Tags: c++, qt

Quiero implementar un diálogo que se ejecute de forma automática al comienzo de un programa si los datos de una conexión a una BBDD no están bien. Una vez configurados los datos de conexión, y si éstos están bien, se activará un botón de Aceptar y se abrirá la aplicación, o se pulsará Cancelar. Si se cancela cuando se ha entrado de esta forma (automática), la aplicación deberá terminarse.

Este diálogo puede ser llamado posteriormente en cualquier momento para modificar datos de conexión. En este caso, si se pulsa Cancelar, el diálogo sólo debe cerrarse y la aplicación continuará.

Una vez expuesta la idea, muestro un ejemplo que tratará de imitar el comportamiento que quiero conseguir. En este caso es un widget que siempre que se inicie llamará al presunto diálogo de configuración. Si pulso el botón de Aceptar, se vuelve al "principal". Pero si pulso Cancelar cuando se abre de forma automática (al comienzo), debería salirse de la aplicación, pero si lo hago cuando el diálogo se ha abierto pulsando el botón en la ventana principal, debería simplemente cerrar el diálogo y volver a la ventana principal.

He intentado jugar (se ve en el ejemplo) con el valor de `parent()`. Para ello he pretendido que cuando el diálogo se abra de forma automática, sea sin padre  en el constructor, y cuando se haga mediante el botón, sí tenga como padre el widget principal, pero no me ha funcionado.

Dejo el código:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "widget.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**wdget.h** (la ventana principal)

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class QPushButton;
class QHBoxLayout;

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Widget();

private:

    QHBoxLayout* layout;
    QPushButton* boton_Configurar;

public slots:
    void Configurar();
};
#endif // WIDGET_H
```

**widget.cpp**

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "dialogoconfigurar.h"

#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent):QWidget(parent)
{
    layout =  new QHBoxLayout(this);
    boton_Configurar = new QPushButton("Configurar");
    layout->addWidget(boton_Configurar);
    bool res = false;
    if (!res)
    {
        DialogoConfigurar* d = new DialogoConfigurar;
        d->exec();
    }
    QObject::connect(boton_Configurar, &QPushButton::clicked, [=](){Configurar();});
}

Widget::~Widget()
{

}

void Widget::Configurar()
{
    DialogoConfigurar* d = new DialogoConfigurar(this);
    d->exec();
}
```

**dialogoconfigurar.h**

```
    #ifndef DIALOGOCONFIGURAR_H
    #define DIALOGOCONFIGURAR_H
    
    #include <QDialog>
    
    class QPushButton;
    class QHBoxLayout;
    
    class DialogoConfigurar : public QDialog
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    
    public:
        explicit DialogoConfigurar(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
        ~DialogoConfigurar();
    
    public slots:
        void Salir();
    
    private:
        QHBoxLayout* layout;
        QPushButton* boton_Aceptar;
        QPushButton* boton_Salir;
    };
    
    #endif // DIALOGOCONFIGURAR_H
```

**dialogoconfigurar.cpp**

```
#include "dialogoconfigurar.h"    
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>


DialogoConfigurar::DialogoConfigurar(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent)
{
    layout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
    boton_Aceptar = new QPushButton("Aceptar");
    boton_Salir = new QPushButton("Salir");
    layout->addWidget(boton_Aceptar);
    layout->addWidget(boton_Salir);
    QObject::connect(boton_Aceptar, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &DialogoConfigurar::done);
    QObject::connect(boton_Salir, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &DialogoConfigurar::Salir);

}

DialogoConfigurar::~DialogoConfigurar()
{

}

void DialogoConfigurar::Salir()
{
    qDebug()<<parent();
    if (!parent())
    {
        QApplication::exit();//no funciona
    }
    else
    {
        this->done(0);
    }
}
```

(En el slot `void Salir()` es donde he intentado implementar la lógica del botón)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes llamar a `QApplication::exit()` desde la función `Salir`

Si revisas el `main`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;  // <<-- Se construye Widget -> Se construye DialogoConfigurar -> Se invoca QApplicationExit
    w.show();
    return a.exec(); // <<--- AQUI empieza a funcionar QApplication
}
```

`a.exec()` es la función que inicializa el bucle de eventos. Pieza clave de toda aplicación gráfica. Sin esa función, tu aplicación se queda *tonta*, pues esa función es la que procesa todos los eventos y señales que llegan de Windows.

Si necesitas hacer esos chequeos al inicio, y esos chequeos no tienen que hacer uso de ningún objeto que requiera el uso de señales y slots de Qt, puedes simplemente dejarlo en el `main`:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);

bool chequeo = false;
if (!chequeo)
{
    DialogoConfigurar dlg;
    dlg.show();
    return a.exec();
}

Widget w;
w.show();
return a.exec();
```

Comment: Este era el enfoque. Funciona perfecto!

Comment: He añadido una pequeña modificación a tu respuesta para que tenga exactamente el comportamiento que necesitaba.

Comment: Bien, la he borrado porque no me funcionaba realmente. Mi modificación consistía en hacer algo como: `int ret = dlg.exec(); if (ret == QDialog::Rejected) { return a.exec(); }` pero me he dado cuenta con el método `exec()` de que no salgo bien del programa.

Comment: @user3733164 eso solo funciona con dialogos secundarios, el dialogo principal, el que inicia la aplicación, no puede usar ese mecanismo. Esto es así porque el método `exec` no se puede invocar si no están activas las señales... y éstas no se activan hasta que no llamas a `app.exec`

Comment: Hola @eferion, entendido. He hecho otra prueba, que al menos funciona. Hago la comprobación en el constructor de `MainWindow` , y si salgo del diálogo de configurar termino la aplicación con `exit(int)` Voy a poner el código

Answer (score 0):

He hecho otra propuesta que parece funcionar:

**dialogoconfigurar.h**

```
#ifndef DIALOGOCONFIGURAR_H
#define DIALOGOCONFIGURAR_H

#include <QDialog>

class QPushButton;
class QVBoxLayout;

class DialogoConfigurar : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit DialogoConfigurar(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~DialogoConfigurar();    

private:
    QVBoxLayout* layout;
    QPushButton* boton_Aceptar;
    QPushButton* boton_Salir;
};

#endif // DIALOGOCONFIGURAR_H
```

**dialogoconfigurar.cpp**

```
#include "dialogoconfigurar.h"

#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>


DialogoConfigurar::DialogoConfigurar(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent)
{    
    setWindowTitle("Configurar");
    layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    boton_Aceptar = new QPushButton("Aceptar");
    boton_Salir = new QPushButton("Salir");
    layout->addWidget(boton_Aceptar);
    layout->addWidget(boton_Salir);
    QObject::connect(boton_Aceptar, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &DialogoConfigurar::accept);
    QObject::connect(boton_Salir, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &DialogoConfigurar::reject);
}

DialogoConfigurar::~DialogoConfigurar()
{

}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class QPushButton;
class QHBoxLayout;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void Configurar();

private:
    QDialog* dialogo;
    QHBoxLayout* layout;
    QPushButton* boton_Configurar, *boton_Salir;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "dialogoconfigurar.h"

#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QDialogButtonBox>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QApplication>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    bool chequeo = false;
    //bool chequeo = true;
    if (!chequeo)
    {
        DialogoConfigurar dlg;
        int ret = dlg.exec();
        if (ret == QDialog::Rejected)
        {
            qDebug()<<"Salir ";
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    setWindowTitle("Aplicacion principal");
    dialogo =  new QDialog;
    layout =  new QHBoxLayout;
    boton_Configurar = new QPushButton("Configurar");
    boton_Salir = new QPushButton("Salir");
    layout->addWidget(boton_Configurar);
    layout->addWidget(boton_Salir);
    dialogo->setLayout(layout);
    setCentralWidget(dialogo);

    QObject::connect(boton_Configurar, &QPushButton::clicked, [=](){Configurar();});
    QObject::connect(boton_Salir, &QPushButton::clicked, [=](){close();});
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}

void MainWindow::Configurar()
{
    DialogoConfigurar* d = new DialogoConfigurar(this);
    d->show();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow m;
    m.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Von esta propuesta te puedes encontrar exactamente con el mismo problema. En el momento de invocar el constructor de `mainwindow` aún no se ha iniciado `QApplication`, luego las señales y slots, entre otras cosas, aún no están operativos

Comment: ¡Es verdad! Bueno, pues toca seguir investigando. Es cierto que debería de tener las señales y slots funcionando en el ejemplo real, luego no me funcionará.